# Each thread create its own logger instance, logging their own event

Tags: python, multithreading, logging

I have tried logging in Python. It looks like once a logging instance is created by a thread it won't be deleted. However, my program should produce more than 100 threads per minute, and each will create their own logger, which may result in a kind of memory leak (`logging.Logger` instances will not be collected by the garbage collector).

Can anyone help me on this, is there a way to use logger for multi-threaded applications?

Comment: Can you post some code that demonstrates this memory leak?

Answer (score 2):

In the python `logging` module, loggers are managed by a `logging.Manager` instance. usually there is only one logging manager, available as `logging.Logger.manager`. Loggers are identified by their name. Each time you use `logging.getLogger('name')` this call is acutally forwarded to `logging.Logger.manager.getLogger` which holds a dict of loggers and returns the same logger for each `'name'` every time.

so if you don't use a different name when getting the logger from a thread, you're actually using the same logger instance each time and don't have to worry about a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks! mata, resolved problem that according  to your advise! thanks a lot!